# Minizinc - Implementing count constraint

Tags: minizinc

I am working on this problem. I have two decision variables x and y. For same values in x, and corresponding same values in y, I have to count the occurences of this value in y.
I have tried to implement it. But I have doubts that the functionality is as expected.

My code

```
set of int: x = 1..4;
set of int: y = 1..3;
set of int: a = 1..10;
set of int: b = 1..5;

%Decision variables
array[x, y] of var a: recordA;
array[x, y] of var b: recordB;

constraint  forall(i in x ) (
                alldifferent([recordB[i,j] | j in y])
                );
constraint  forall(i in x ) (
                alldifferent([recordA[i,j] | j in y])
                ); 

%constraint forall(i,k in x, j in y where i<k /\ recordB[i,j]=recordB[k,j]) (
%            forall(i,k in x,j in y where recordA[i,j]=recordA[k,j])(
%                 count(recordA, recordA[i,j]) 
%);
OR

%Maybe something like this
%constraint forall(i in x, j in y, m in b)(
%                  count(col(recordA, j),count(col(recordB,j),m))
 %           );
```

The idea is for every recorB and every recordA, to go through all the y (for all the x) and count how many values occur the same recordB at corresponding the same recordA.

For Example- for a value r1 in recordB->count of number of values r2 occuring in recordA.

[image: Example]

In this case, recordB has three occurences of value 4 at recordB[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c4cE.png)], recordB[6] and recordB[11]
correspondingly recordA has two occurrences of value 5 at recordA[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c4cE.png)], recordA[6] but at recordA[11] the value is 1.

I want to count these occurrences of same values in recordA corresponding wuth recordB.

And each row of recordA is unique
And each row of recordB is unique

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: It would be great if you can clarify your question a bit. I do not understand exactly understand what you are trying to count. Are `x` and `y` variables or integer sets? Are trying to match the number of occurrences of values between `recordA` and `recordB`? Are you trying to find specific values or just counting occurrences for all values?

Comment: I have added some details to my question. And yes, x and y are sets. I have fixed that too. Thanks